How to encrypt/decrypt the zipfile?
Using certificate, when apply the encryption and decryption for a text file data, it works. But if use different file format for example .zip file, after encryption/decryption, the output of the .zip file is corrupted.
Any idea how could achieve encryption/decryption for the .zip file? Does that encryption/decryption support .zip files?
Thanks in advance...
public static byte[] EncryptDataOaepSha1(X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] data)
{
    // GetRSAPublicKey returns an object with an independent lifetime, so use a using statement.
    using (RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey())
    {
        // OAEP allows for multiple hashing algorithms; here we use OAEP-SHA1.
        return rsa.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
    }
}

public static byte[] DecryptDataOaepSha1(X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] data)
{
    // GetRSAPrivateKey returns an object with an independent lifetime, so use a using statement.
    using (RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
    {
        return rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
    }
}

Reference link : Encrypt / Decrypt in C# using Certificate

Encryption works with bytes, so it is irrelevant whether it is a text file, a .zip file or anything else. Your problem will therefore have other causes. RSA is only possible for small amounts of data (key size minus a padding-dependent value). Your data may be too large. For larger amounts of data, symmetric (e.g. AES) or hybrid (e.g. RSA + AES) encryption must be used. How large is your zip file?

I can say it comes around ~2 GB

Far too much for RSA. With a 2048 bits key and OAEP/SHA1, a maximum of 214 bytes can be encrypted with RSA, see here. Try e.g. a hybrid encryption with RSA/AES: Encrypt the data with AES and the AES key with RSA.

It would also take forever to encrypt 2GB with 2048-bit RSA.
